# How to view Domain startup script?

Tags: windows-7, script, active-directory, domain, windows-domain

I am Local Admin on our machines but not Domain Admin.

When I go to `rsop.msc` to view the Group Policies applied, I can see that there is a startup script executed from `%logonserver%\sysvol\ourdomain\scripts\blah\blah.VBS`.

Is there a way I can open and view the script to see what it does?

Comment: If you copy and paste `%logonserver%\sysvol\ourdomain\scripts\blah` into the address bar of Windows Explorer, you should find `blah.VBS` in that folder and should be able to open it with Notepad.

Comment: I feel dumb. :-)